# facebook puts access code in web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

Trying to write a facebook app and am attempting authentication. This is a rails 3.1 application

The First redirect where I give facebook my api and it returns a code seems to run well.  But when I try to take that code and 'exchange it' from a access_token I run into problems.

The access token appears where the iframe aws.

Here is my code.

```
def index
#Load facebook.yml info
config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml"));
# setup client

redirect_to "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=#{config['development']['app_id']}&redirect_uri=#{CALLBACK_URI}"

end
def callback

   logger.debug("c")
  config = YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/facebook.yml"));
  if (!params.key?('access_token'))
     logger.debug("A")
     redirect_to "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=#    {config['development']['app_id']}&redirect_uri=#{CALLBACK_URI}&client_secret=#{config['development']['client_secret']}&code=#{params['code']}"
   return
 end
   logger.debug("B")
 access_token = params['access_token']
 @me = FbGraph::User.me(ACCESS_TOKEN)
 @name=@me.name

 end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** supposed to *redirect* the user’s browser to the second endpoint (*think* for a moment, you are putting your app secret into that URL, so it would be easy for everyone to spot it there) – you are supposed to make a **server-side call** to that endpoint.

The docs *clearly* say so, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/:

> *“Once the user has authorized your app, you should make a **server side** request to exchange the code returned above for a user access token.”*